# Nvidia driver started to break my apt environment, how can I fix this?

Tags: apt

After I did a series of commands to install Nvidia driver and nvidia-cuda-toolkit things, it started to log stdout errors whenever I try `apt install`.

I don't remember what exactly commands I've ran, but I think at least I did the following for instance:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
sudo apt install nvidia-340
```

Here is an example output that I get when I do a `apt install`:

```
$ sudo apt install cowsay -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
cowsay is already the newest version (3.03+dfsg2-7).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  g++-8 libaccinj64-10.1 libatomic1:i386 libbsd0:i386 libcublas10 libcublaslt10 libcudart10.1 libcufft10 libcufftw10 libcuinj64-10.1
  libcupti-dev libcupti-doc libcupti10.1 libcurand10 libcusolver10 libcusolvermg10 libcusparse10 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386
  libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libedit2:i386 libelf1:i386 libexpat1:i386 libffi7:i386
  libfwupdplugin1 libgl1:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386 libglvnd0:i386 libglx-mesa0:i386 libglx0:i386 libllvm12:i386
  libncurses5 libnppc10 libnppial10 libnppicc10 libnppicom10 libnppidei10 libnppif10 libnppig10 libnppim10 libnppist10 libnppisu10
  libnppitc10 libnpps10 libnvblas10 libnvgraph10 libnvidia-ml-dev libnvjpeg10 libnvrtc10.1 libnvtoolsext1 libnvvm3 libpciaccess0:i386
  libsensors5:i386 libstdc++-8-dev libstdc++6:i386 libthrust-dev libtinfo5 libvdpau-dev libvulkan1:i386 libwayland-client0:i386
  libx11-6:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386
  libxcb-randr0:i386 libxcb-shm0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb-xfixes0:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386
  libxshmfence1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 libzstd1:i386 mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 nvidia-cuda-dev nvidia-cuda-doc nvidia-cuda-gdb
  nvidia-opencl-dev nvidia-profiler nvidia-visual-profiler ocl-icd-opencl-dev opencl-c-headers
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 102 not upgraded.
8 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up nvidia-dkms-450 (450.51.05-0ubuntu1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)

A modprobe blacklist file has been created at /etc/modprobe.d to prevent Nouveau
from loading. This can be reverted by deleting the following file:
/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf

A new initrd image has also been created. To revert, please regenerate your
initrd by running the following command after deleting the modprobe.d file:
`/usr/sbin/initramfs -u`

*****************************************************************************
*** Reboot your computer and verify that the NVIDIA graphics driver can   ***
*** be loaded.                                                            ***
*****************************************************************************

INFO:Enable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (Dialog frontend requires a screen at least 13 lines tall and 31 columns wide.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Removing old nvidia-450.51.05 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 450.51.05
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new nvidia-450.51.05 DKMS files...
Building for 5.15.0-56-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.15.0-56-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/nvidia-dkms-450.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.15.0-56-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/450.51.05/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-450 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-dkms-450 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-450:
 nvidia-driver-450 depends on nvidia-dkms-450 (= 450.51.05-0ubuntu1); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-450 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-450 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda-drivers-450:
 cuda-drivers-450 depends on nvidia-dkms-450 (>= 450.51.05); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-450 is not configured yet.
 cuda-drivers-450 depends on nvidia-driver-450 (>= 450.51.05); however:
  Package nvidia-driver-450 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-drivers-450 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda-drivers:
 cuda-drivers depends on cuda-drivers-450 (= 450.51.05-1); however:
  Package cuda-drivers-450 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-drivers (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                 No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                               dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda-runtime-11-0:
 cuda-runtime-11-0 depends on cuda-drivers (>= 450.51.05); however:
  Package cuda-drivers is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-runtime-11-0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda-11-0:
 cuda-11-0 depends on cuda-runtime-11-0 (>= 11.0.2); however:
  Package cuda-runtime-11-0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-11-0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda-demo-suite-11-0:
 cuda-demo-suite-11-0 depends on cuda-runtime-11-0; however:
  Package cuda-runtime-11-0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-demo-suite-11-0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda:
 cuda depends on cuda-11-0 (>= 11.0.2); however:
  Package cuda-11-0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.7) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-56-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-dkms-450
 nvidia-driver-450
 cuda-drivers-450
 cuda-drivers
 cuda-runtime-11-0
 cuda-11-0
 cuda-demo-suite-11-0
 cuda
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The `apt install` itself is working, so for example the above installs `cowsay` successfully, but simply the long error output is just disturbing and since it always ends the command with an error code I cannot tell if the command is succeeded by `echo $?`.

Ubuntu version (added):

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

How can I fix this and get rid of the error messages?

Comment: *deb* packages are built for specific releases, so it's easiest if you actually tell us what OS/release you're using.  It looks like *focal* (20.04), but rather than us guess - it's most helpful if we're told, as that allows us to provide more accurate help for you.  What OS/release are you actually running?

Comment: Thanks, that's correct, it's 20.04. I'm adding to the edit.

Comment: You're rather behind on security fixes & patches etc..  An updated system has reported itself as 20.04.5 for some time now (refer https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/09/01/ubuntu-20-04-5-lts-released/ which shows the ISO release date, but installed systems upgraded before that date).  I'd suggest applying all upgrades asap (*esp. if the box is online; and after all upgrades are applied you may have fewer issues, though I suspect it won't help with in your current case*)